# Mockito on android throwing lang exception

Tags: mockito, android-testing

I am learning the MVP architecture that google uses in their android codelabs. I have set up a simple example. Two input fields and a "+" button to show the addition result. The view is the main activity and I have a presenter that calls a service to add the two input values. The view passes itself to the presenter in the onCreate method and keeps a reference of the presenter as well.

View Interface:

```
public interface MainView {

    String getFirstInput();

    void showFirstInputError(int resId);

    String getSecondInput();

    void showSecondInputError(int resId);

    void setResultText(int result);
}
```

Presenter method that is called when the button is pressed:

```
public void onResultClicked(){
        String firstInput = view.getFirstInput();
        String secondInput = view.getSecondInput();

        if(firstInput.isEmpty()) {
            view.showFirstInputError(R.string.num_input_error);
            return;
        }

        if(secondInput.isEmpty()) {
            view.showSecondInputError(R.string.num_input_error);
            return;
        }

        Service service = new Service();

        int result = service.add(Integer.getInteger(firstInput),
                Integer.getInteger(secondInput));

        view.setResultText(result);

    }
```

Test:

```
@Test
    public void shouldPopulateResultWhenButtonIsClicked() throws Exception {
        when(view.getFirstInput()).thenReturn("3");
        when(view.getSecondInput()).thenReturn("3");
        when(service.add(3,3)).thenReturn(6);
        presenter.onResultClicked();
        verify(service).add(3,3);
        verify(view).setResultText(6);
    }
```

I get an error on the line the service is trying to add the two inputs.

```
presenter.onResultClicked();
int result = service.add(Integer.getInteger(firstInput),
                    Integer.getInteger(secondInput));
```

Can somebody please help. Thanks.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.ulidder.tdd_mvp_simple.MainPresenter.onResultClicked(MainPresenter.java:29)
    at com.example.ulidder.tdd_mvp_simple.MainPresenterTest.shouldPopulateResultWhenButtonIsClicked(MainPresenterTest.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
```

Comment: What is at line 29 of MainPresenter.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with Android, Mockito or MVP, you're running a jUnit test, it's pure Java.

It's just a `NullPointerException`, nothing else. Go to line 29 of `MainPresenter.java`, add a breakpoint and launch the test in debug mode to see which method call is made on a null reference. Extract variables from chained calls if necessary.

I suspect that `service.add(...)` returns an `java.lang.Integer` and you're assigning it to an `int`. If it returns null, the unboxing will get you a `NullPointerException` at this line. Try assigning the return value to an `Integer` and debug the value. It may be null.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382058/unboxing-null-object-to-long-results-in-nullpointerexception-fine) for more information about unboxing of null values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I was using the wrong method to convert String to Integer. It is a java issue as you pointed out. Integer.getInteger() determines the integer value of the system property with the specified name. This was resulting in NPE.

I have another quick one - for verify(service).method(), it will only verify that the method() is called on the mock service object right? Not that it is called on any service instance. I think I am right. Want to confirm. If so, I need to pass the service to the presenter to test it is being called. Thank you again !