# Why is there a NullPointerException in this method call?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

When I call a method like this:

```
int value1;
Integer value2 = null;

setValue(value2);

private void setValue(int value) {
    value1 = value;
}
```

Why is there a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Depends on the implementation of `setValue`

Comment: with just this line no

Comment: @JigarJoshi. You have no way of knowing that.

Comment: A NullPointerException often happens when you try to access the fields or methods of a null reference. It will not happen if you just set a reference to null.

Comment: twis just this line no.

Comment: Ok. Then your question is a dupelicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382058/unboxing-null-object-to-long-results-in-nullpointerexception-fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case which hasn't been mentioned in the current answers is if the formal parameter type is primitive:

```
void setValue(int a) {
  // ...
}
```

This can be called with a parameter `null`, because the compiler will attempt to auto-unbox the value. Effectively:

```
setValue(null);
```

Would be invoked as:

```
setValue(((Integer) null).intValue());
```

However, this will always fail with NPE, because you can't dereference a null value.

But note that the NPE doesn't occur because `null` is passed to the method, but rather because of how the value which would be passed is evaluated. The difference is subtle, but important.

Any IDE worth using should flag this as a problem.

Comment: Is that even gonna compile?

Comment: @Shadov, it compiles in Apache Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if `setValue()` does access the object like this:

```
void setValue(Long lung) {
    this.val = lung.intValue();
}
```

because it tries to dereference `null`. and no, if `setValue()` does treat the object like that:

```
void setValue(Long lung) {
    this.val = Optional.ofNullable(lung)
                       .map(Long::intValue)
                       .orElse(0L) ;
}
```

because it is aware of how to handle `null`.

**The point is:** if the method which receives the `null` argument does dereference it inside the method body, or pass it to some method which does, a `NullPointerException` will be thrown. Otherwise not.

Comment: What if it's just `this.val = val;`? Also, `long` is not a valid parameter name: it's a primitive type name.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: you got me ... nice. Will fix it. Doing it in the train and haven't open an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

`Null Pointer Exception` happens when you try to call a method on `null` reference. So when you are calling that method and any where you are using that argument to call some method you will get a `Null Pointer Exception`, otherwise if you are passing it into an API of JAVA or someone else and if the same thing happens inside then also you will jump into `NPE`. So `debug` your code properly to find the possible places where you might get `Exception` and give null checks.

```
void setValue(Object value) {

     // case : 1
     int i = (Integer) value;

     // case : 2
     int i = value.toString().length();

     // case : 3
     value.getSomethingElse();

}
```

These are the possible cases where you will be getting `NPE`. But if you are just calling this method to simply set some derived attribute, its fine because `null` can be assigned to any derived attribute. But if you call any method on that attribute after setting it to null then the result will be the same.

```
class Foo {

     private String entity;
     public void setEntity(String entity) {
          this.entity = entity;
     }
     public String getEntity() {
          return entity;
     }
}
class FooManager {

      public static void main(String[] arg) {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.setEntity(null);
            System.out.println(foo.getEntity().length());   //NPE
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `NullPointerException` is generally thrown when the JVM expected a valid object reference but got `null` instead. A very common specific case of this is when you set a reference to `null` and then try to call a method or access a field on that reference.

Given the information you have given, it is impossible tell if your code will throw an exception.

If the setter just assigns a reference, it will not throw anything immediately, because you can pretty much assign `null` to anything that is not a primitive. This is not to say that you will not get the exception later when you try to access the object you just set.

If the setter performs any type of actions directly on the reference you passed in, without checking if it is `null` first, you are likely to get an exception. Most likely, however, if the setter is well written, it will perform some checks and take appropriate action before blindly using the passed-in reference.

Answer (score 0):

A NullPointerException is thrown whenever you try to access something on a null-Reference.

Let's say we have this method:

```
public static String test(Object obj)
{
    return obj.toString();
}
```

And we invoke it like this:

```
test(new Object());
```

Everything will work fine.

But if we invoke the method with null:

```
test(null);
```

a NullPointerException will be thrown.

Looking at the StackTrace you will see, that the NullPointerException was thrown in this line:

```
return obj.toString();
```

That's because we tried to invoke the Method "toString" on a null-Reference.

So we see, that not giving the Method a null-Parameter, but invoking a Method on a null-Reference causes a NullPointerException. Some Methods check if the Parameter is null and have a special action for that. Often it's even very useful. But most methods will require the parameters not to be null.