# Unboxing Integer cast from null

Tags: java, autoboxing

What is the value of `i` when you execute the code below and why?

```
int i = (Integer)null;
```

Comment: I already did. It's the why that interests me most, an may be useful to other people.

Comment: @Gustavo "why" is "because it was designed like that", and it's documented in the relevant JLS.

Comment: Ok. But comments is not the right place to answer.

Comment: Null gets correctly cast to an Integer. Java attempts to unbox the integer into a primitive int so that it may store it in the variable, effectively calling `null.intValue()` which results in a NPE.

Comment: Guys, the section below is the right place to answer, not here. Also, this is not a duplicate, because it's not about casting, but about unboxing.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382058/unboxing-null-object-to-primitive-type-results-in-nullpointerexception-fine , should probably be updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [jls5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8):

> At run time, unboxing conversion proceeds as follows:
>
> ...
>
> If r is null, unboxing conversion throws a NullPointerException