# unboxing of snapshot.getvalue(double.class) may produce nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Snapshot.getValue is producing null pointer exception,how should i solve this error?

```
DatabaseReference offsetRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/serverTimeOffset");
        offsetRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                double offset = snapshot.getValue(Double.class);
```

Comment: It sounds like `.info/serverTimeOffset` may not exist, which means that the `Double` you get out of it is `null`, which can't be unboxed. The solution would be to make the type `Double offset = ...` or to unbox after checking for `null`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382058/unboxing-null-object-to-primitive-type-results-in-nullpointerexception-fine

Answer (score 0):

`snapshot.getValue(Double.class)` returns a `Double` object, not a `double` primitive.  You should check this object for null before unboxing it.  It can be null when no data exists in the snapshot.

```
Double offset = snapshot.getValue(Double.class);
if (offset != null) {
    double o = offset;
}
else {
    // figure out what you want to do when the data is not there
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. You can write it in a `try...catch`

```
double offset;

try {
    offset = snapshot.getValue(Double.class);
}catch(Exception e){
    offset = 0; //Default value
}
```

Another option is to use a ternary operator

```
double offset = snapshot.getValue(Double.class) != null ? snapshot.getValue(Double.class) : 0;
```