# Why does this Java code using HashMap cause NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

This is what I encountered solving leetcode problem [954. Array of Doubled Pairs](https://leetcode.com/problems/array-of-doubled-pairs/).

Here's a global map which stores the count on each value. I use this function below to check if the values in the list (which is also in the map) are all paired (if the map has `value` and  `value * 2`).

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> map;
    
    private boolean isPaired( List<Integer> list) {
         for(int key : list) {
            if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                if (map.containsKey(key * 2)) {
                    updateMap(key);
                    updateMap(key * 2);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    private void updateMap(int key) {
        int value = map.get(key);
        if (value - 1 == 0) {
            map.remove(key); 
        } else {
            map.put(key , value - 1); 
        }
    }
```

with the case (9945 0s, 10052 1s and 10003 2s), it throws NullPointerException. Here's the exception message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at line 54, Solution.updateMap
  at line 44, Solution.isPaired
  at line 26, Solution.canReorderDoubled
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 84, __Driver__.main
```

And as I changed the function `isPaired` into the code below:

```
 private boolean isPaired(List<Integer> list) {
         for(int key : list) {
            if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                updateMap(key);
                if (map.containsKey(key * 2)) {
                    updateMap(key * 2);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

NullPointerException doesn't occur anymore.
Why do these happen?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [mre] and the full details of the error you are getting.

Comment: Thank you for your advice [khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NullPointerException (NPE) occurs in the first case because `key` and `key*2` are the same value when `key=0`.  The second version of the code tests for the presence of `key*2` after the first mapping has already been removed so it doesn't encounter the NPE.

Comment: Thank you [vsfDawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7275056/vsfdawg). I got it!

Answer (score 0):

`map.get()` can return `null` (if the key is not found).

If you try to assign `null` to a variable of primitive type `int`, you get a `NullPointerException` (see also [Unboxing Null-Object to primitive type results in NullPointerException, fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382058/unboxing-null-object-to-primitive-type-results-in-nullpointerexception-fine)).

So, if you don't check if the value exists via `map.containsKey(key)` or check the result for `null` before converting it to `int`, you get an exception.

As already mentioned correctly in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68742572/2513200), your modified version checks for existence of the second key after the first modification, and this works even if both keys are the same value (this is the case for `0`) and the first modification removes the key the second modification looks for.

Comment: Thank you [Hulk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2513200/hulk). However, what bothers me is that ```map.containsKey(key)``` and ```map.containsKey(key * 2) ```  are both met, but the map.get(key) returned null.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I updated my answer with the correct information from vsfDawg's answer that the case of `0` is important here.

Answer (score 0):

Your map can only contain objects of type Integer with keys of type Integer.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

When the map does not contain an object for a specific key it will return null.

```
map.get(key); --> will return a null-Integer
```

When you try to unbox a Integer-Object to an int-value this will throw NullPointerException, when the Integer-Object is null.

```
int value = map.get(key); // throws NullPointerException
```

Let´s try this in jshell. So open a console-window and start JShell with *jshell*:[image]

Comment: Thank you [Tobias Otto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6643833/tobias-otto). I will try this in jshell.