# Can an assignment statement cause a null-pointer exception?

Tags: java, exception

This code snippet is reading camera picture Exif metadata using ExifInterface:
Apparently, one particular picture has no or invalid datetime and
.getDateTime() is returning null. In the code I assign it to a long, dt, and that
results in the exception that is shown below. Of course, if I un-comment the null-check
just prior to the assignment, all is well.

So, I have 1 question and 1 lesson:

1. I'm assuming getDateTime() is really the culprit. Can an assignment cause such a exception?
2. As you see, the offending line is within try/catch but it wasn't catching it because
   I was catching only IOException. When it was changed to Exception, it caught.

   ```
            String latlong = "";
            long dt = 0;
            ExifInterface exifInterface;
            try {
                exifInterface = new ExifInterface(pf.getAbsolutePath());
                if (exifInterface != null)
                {
                    float[] latLng = new float[2];
                    if (exifInterface.getLatLong(latLng)) { //file has exif latlong info
                        //etc, latLng[0] is your latitute value and latLng[1] your longitude value
                        latlong = latLng[0] + "," + latLng[1];
                    }
                    //if (exifInterface.getDateTime() != null)
                      dt = exifInterface.getDateTime();
                    picInfo.comments = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_USER_COMMENT);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>ERROR: cameraPicTask.doInBackground");
                    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>-----: null exifInterface for: " + pf.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
   ```

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.example.mypics, PID: 7912
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.mypics.PicsActivity$cameraPicTask.doInBackground(PicsActivity.java:211)
        at com.example.mypics.PicsActivity$cameraPicTask.doInBackground(PicsActivity.java:185)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

Comment: Line 211 in your  PicsActivity.java file contains code that dereferences a pointer that is null. Simple as that.

Comment: Looks like code around here `//if (exifInterface.getDateTime() != null)` is necessary - no?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382058/unboxing-null-object-to-primitive-type-results-in-nullpointerexception-fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `exifInterface.getDateTime()` returns a `Long`, and in this case, it returns `null`. You assign it to `long dt` which involves an [unboxing operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). The compiler emits code to convert the `Long` to a `long` by calling `longValue()` on it, which throws the NPE. You can see it in your stack trace:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference

Even if you were to assign it to a `Long` first:

```
Long dateTime = exifInterface.getDateTime();
long dt = dateTime;
```

it would still have to unbox it, and thus, yes, an assignment can throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Another lesson learned: Long is not long and a good coder must think like a compiler.
Thanks David...

Comment: @HongSon Yes, among other things, Java generics can (currently) only use reference types, so for instance you can't have a list of primitive types like `List<long>` or `List<int>`. Thus, `Long` and "boxing" is needed. There is a plan for a future version of Java that would allow generics with primitive types (Project Valhalla), although when that will become available is yet to be seen.